Why is length through log10 faster then traditional method?
Yesterday I encountered the Leetcode question called Even digits numbers in an array where I should, given an array nums of integers, return how many of them contain an even number of digits. I did solve it before using while loop then also found out log is faster, but why?
I was trying to solve a Leetcode question, i.e even digits, and I already knew logarithmic was the best way to solve, but I don't understand why it is faster then running a while loop. What really goes under the hood to make it faster? Because the general method is good, i.e:
# for finding length of n
int count = 0
while(n < 0){
 n = n/10;
 count++;
}

Why is int count = (int)Math.log10(n)+1 faster? Does it use bit manipulation or anything?

Let me ask you this, why do you think a call to log should be slower than a custom loop calculating (almost) the same thing ?

It's going to be implemented with the FPU or with SSE instructions. See this answer, note that log10(x) can be calculated with log2(x)/log2(10) and that cane be done with SSE.

When a question is based on a problem on a web page, as it would from a programming challenge / practice site, it would be polite, and possibly helpful, to include a link to that page.

Another method for finding the number of digits is along the lines of int count = Integer.toString (Math.abs (n)).length();.  Of the three or more, who decides which is the "traditional" method?

How did you benchmark it? they're both going to be pretty fast, the while loop version might be susceptible to jre warmup where as the log10 function is probably an 'intrinsic'.

< is just a typo, right?

For which types of n did you try to profile this? For int, note that there is a very small set of possible results. Side note: If the task is only to check whether the number is even, you don't really need the precise number of digits. Hint: a small number of comparisons with constants may do, and may be even faster than a call to log().

The logarithmic method for finding the number of digits in an integer is faster due to the way mathematical operations are implemented and optimized in hardware and software.
Traditional While Loop Method
int count = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    n = n / 10;
    count++;
}


Execution: This method involves performing the operation of dividing the number by 10 and incrementing a counter in a loop until the number becomes zero.

Time Complexity: O(d), where d is the number of digits in the number.

Java Example: Notice in bytecode use of temporary variables, and goto



Logarithmic Method
Constant time Complexity regardless of number of digits.
Nowardays we have processors and libraries that are highly optimised implementations for logarthmic functions.
Logarithmic method involves much lesser instructions compared to one generated by a while loop
int count = (int)Math.log10(n) + 1;


Execution: This method uses the mathematical property that the number of digits in a number n is given by ⌊log10(n)⌋ + 1.

Time Complexity: Due to calculation performed as per above direct formula its O(1), constant time complexity.

Java Example: Notice in bytecode direct computation(invokestatic)



Feel free to update or suggest if I missed to add something.

Thank you for wanting to contribute. I wonder about the downvotes and wish that someone would explain them. I also wonder, though, it may be (or may not be) true that logarithm runs in constant time, but if I recall correctly,  quite a number of clock cycles are needed, so how can you claim that they are fewer than the one from the loop? Any calculation, documentation, source?

This looks like LLM generated

another possible reason for downvotes: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

(but some explanation/suggestion how to improve would have been better)

The time complexity isn't really correct. The implementation of log10 can be something else, but it sounds like the argument is "log10 is a function so it's complexity is O(1)" The complexity of the loop is O(log(n)).
